# Android app achievements header lets touch events pass trough

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, achievements-dialog

I was just *randomly playing* with the achievements feed in the Android app, when suddenly a comment of the question underneath it got selected.

**Correct behavior:**

The achievement header should not let touch events pass trough.

**Example:**

[image: Example of the bug]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open any question in the Android app where a comment can be scrolled to just under the ActionBar;
2. Open the achievements screen;
3. Press on the achievements header (obvious not the close button).

**Info:**

- App version: 1.0.56
- Android version: 4.4.4

Comment: This is an awesome catch, thanks for reporting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! It's fixed in version 1.0.57 coming out later today.